# Not able to add a knowledge base (QnA maker) to a bot framework skill

Tags: botframework

Not able to add a knowledge base (QnA maker) to a bot  framework skill. The template provides deployemnt scripts that seems to be able to take care of adding QnA makers to the skill. What am I missing? I have followed the below steps:

Just like we would add new qna makers/knowledge bases in a Virtual Assistant I follow the below steps for adding it to a Skill:

1. Create a Skill using the latest Skills template(C#) - [you can find it here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.VirtualAssistantTemplate)
2. Deploy the skill to Azure using deploy.ps1 that you can find in the solution's 
   "/Deployement/Scripts/" folder
3. Update the cognitivemodels.json with the required details of the qna maker - add the details in the "knowledgebases" - format given below:

   "knowledgebases": [
           {
             "id": "hr",
             "subscriptionKey": "",
             "hostname": "https://.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker",
             "kbId": "kbId",
             "name": "",
             "endpointKey": ""
           }
         ]
4. Run the update_cognitive_models.ps1 in the same folder as above.
5. When I run the above script, I get an error- given below:
   [image]

Error in logs: AZ CLI passes minimum version. Current version is 2.6.0
Sorry unable to open [C:\Users\jyotikub\source\repos\MyAssistant1\TestHRSkill\TestHRSkill\Deployment\Scripts..\Resources\QnA\en-us\hr.json]

Isn't the update_cognitive_model supposed to create the hr.json file?

Please note that I have tested adding the same QnA to a Virtual Assistant and it works fine. I have double checked the values for each of the keys provided and they are correct.

Comment: It's very hard to help you with your specific problem if you don't even let us know what you're working with/post any code. You say "The template"--which template? What language are you working with? That being said a **skill is a bot**, so the process of adding QnA Maker to your skill should be the same as adding it to any old bot. You can see how it's added in [botbuilder-samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker) or see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61354399/9781122)

Comment: @Zeryth, thanks for your response. I have updated my question with details. Apologies about missing on providing the details.